# Show UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation and allow user to switch to text

Tags: ios

I would like to display the `UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation` first to the user, but allow them to switch the default letter keyboard if they wish. When I set my `keyboardType` to `UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation`, there isn't an option to switch to the default keyboard.

Is there a `keyboardType` that first showing the `UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation` but still allows the user to switch?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use accessory view att the top of your keyboard, to store a button that changes your keyboardInput. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH12-SW1